# Optimisation with coroutine

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I have simple code in Kotlin who made list of request (150) with okhttp lib and for each I parse the html result with JSOUp.

I use Coroutine but I don't understand, the time with or without coroutine are the same (23 secondes)

Maybe I ve done something bad? Or http request is limited ?

My code :

```
fun parse(list: ArrayList<ChampionBean>) {

    runBlocking {
        list.forEach {
            launch {
                   val response = requestWithOkhttp(it.url)
                   val doc = Jsoup.parse(response.body?.string())
                   response.close()
                   parsedocwithJsoup(doc, it)                 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Couple of things. The coroutine you have there will inherit the context, so you might have a context that has 1 thread only. You can print `println("I'm working in thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")` to find the thread name. Also how is the okhttpclient configured? As it could be configured to use only one http connection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Augusto , all my launch was on the same thread. I solve my probleme with launch(Dispatchers.Default)

Comment: @Tenfour04 it's a script and the purpose it's to wait that all the request was done. The main of runblocking it's to wait all of launch/async inside

Answer (score 0):

I just add Dispatchers.Default and it's work. 7seconds instead of 23.
I don't know why, the default dispatcher was not the default dispatcher.
The code was run in main methode in Intellij, without UI

```
 fun parse(list: ArrayList<ChampionBean>) {
    
        runBlocking {
            list.forEach {
                launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
                       val response = requestWithOkhttp(it.url)
                       val doc = Jsoup.parse(response.body?.string())
                       response.close()
                       parsedocwithJsoup(doc, it)                 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And with Dispatchers.IO too many request in the same time so the server stop answer